# How to select top most gameObject in a stack of gameObjects?

Tags: unity, 2d, picking

I'm stuck trying to figure out how I can select the top most GameObject in a stack of GameObjects. In the picture below, I have a Green and Yellow circle stacked on top of each other. If I try to select the top most gameobject (the green one), it selects the yellow circle. Is there a way that I can make sure that when I go to select a circle, it selects the top most one? I'm currently using the OnMouseDown() function built into unity.

*Update* Sorting the colors on the z axis did not solve the problem. I'm still trying to figure out a solution

[image]

Comment: Have you considered separating your objects on the z axis, so there's a consistent ordering to both the display and raycast queries?

Comment: I have and it was still doing the same thing. It didn't seem to matter on where they were placed on the z axis

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting a script with an `OnMouseDown` method on every single game object, create **one** game object with an update-function which

1. uses [`Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html), [`Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) and `Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")` to read the mouse state
2. converts the mouse position on the screen into a ray from the camera positon into the scene using [`Camera.ScreenPointToRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html).
3. Detects the first collider which touches that ray using [`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) or [`Physics2D.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) depending on whether your objects have 3d or 2d colliders.

This, of course, requires that the render order of your SpriteRenderers is managed by their z-position, not by render layers or orders in those render layers.

Code example (untested!)

```
void Update() {

      if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"),
                                                Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"),
                                                0.0f);
            Ray mouseRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(mousePosition); 
            RaycastHit hit;
            if(Physics.Raycast(mouseRay, out hit)) {
                  GameObject clickedObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
                  // do what you want to do with clickedObject
            };
      }
}
```

One advantage of this architecture over [OnMouseDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) is that you decouple the input logic from the game mechanics. If you later want to add different ways to select objects, you don't need to implement that logic in the scripts which handle the game mechanics of selectable objects. You can contain these selection methods in separate scripts. The clicked object might know it is selected, but doesn't need to know how exactly it was selected.